# How to send messages one way from the server to the clients with SignalR SelfHosted Server?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am looking for an example similar to the [StockTicker](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr) example but using a self hosted server and console client application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server side code doesn't change. You'd write your hub the same way. You can learn about how to self host here http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-signalr-self-host.

You can read about how to use the .NET client here:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

That should be all you need to create your app.

Comment: Ok that is what I thought I guess that leads me to another question on how to broadcast new messages on a set interval like checking every 60 seconds for new message in some storage backend and broadcasting them out to clients as well as updating existing ones.

Comment: I see that too here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub

Comment: I am stuck on the client code to process the collection from the stock ticker example in a console client, I will post another question for this.